# FutureBuilder build function must not return Null Error

Tags: flutter

I'm learning flutter and in the exercise I have build an App which is seldomly giving the bellow mentioned error.

I'm unable to identify what part is returning error and why I seldomly get this error and rest of time my App works without this error.

Kindly note even if I get this error after couple of seconds the home screen renders and then the app works perfectly. Because of this I felt that the error was in Loading section and I enclosed my
SpinKitRotatingCircle in a container but it didn't solve the problem.

---

In the MyApp StatelessWidget I'd to create MaterialApp 3 times (one for success, one for pending and one for error). Is their a way whereby I can merge these in a single material app.

---

Code :

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return MaterialApp(
    //   home: Wrapper(),
    // );
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
                title: Text('Error Loading Brew Crew'),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
              body: Center(
                  child: AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Error Loading Brew Crew'),
                content: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => exit(0),
                    child: Text('OK'),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamProvider<User>.value(
            value: AuthService().user,
            child: MaterialApp(
              home: Wrapper(),
            ),
          );
        }
//Loading
        print('Initializing Flutter');
        MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
              title: Text('Loading Brew Crew'),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: SpinKitRotatingCircle(
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 50.0,
            )),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: You should make one `MaterialApp()` and inside it in `home`, you can use the `FutureBuilder` widget, your current structure is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Firebase.initializeApp()` is an async function so for some period of time it won't have a value.

During this time, you're seeing the above error.

When the `initializeApp` completes and a `FirebaseApp` object is returned, your FutureBuilder rebuilds using that object.

Then this part of your FutureBuilder gets executed:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamProvider<User>.value(
            value: AuthService().user,
            child: MaterialApp(
              home: Wrapper(),
            ),
          );
        }
```

**But prior to that**, your `has.error` clause isn't true so that won't run and won't return anything.

And at the bottom of your FutureBuilder you have:

```
 MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
              title: Text('Loading Brew Crew'),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: SpinKitRotatingCircle(
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 50.0,
            )),
          ),
        );
```

Note that you've *created* a MaterialApp, but you haven't `return MaterialApp`.

This is where & why the big red error screen is showing as your FutureBuilder has not returned any Widgets and you're not allowed to return nothing.

You've repeated the MaterialApp widget several times which adds some noise to your code and isn't necessary.  Perhaps try something like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          title: Text('Loading Brew Crew'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                  child: AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Error Loading Brew Crew'),
                    content: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => exit(0),
                        child: Text('OK'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ));
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return StreamProvider<User>.value(
                value: AuthService().user,
                child: Wrapper(),
              );
            }
            return Center(
                child: SpinKitRotatingCircle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 50.0)
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `if (snapshot.hasError)`  and `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)` that return something.
but after two `if`, your `MaterialApp` did not return.
So if your snapshot cant jump into two if, your code won't return anything.
just add `return` to `MaterialApp` under `print('Initializing Flutter');`.